# How should I to add property to Button in XAML file for refreshing WebView2 Window

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, refresh, webview2

I'm pretty new at development of apps with WebView2. Please help.
I have some XAML which represents the window with image  derived from another PC. So sometimes there is a need to refresh this image. Now I have this part of XAML file

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RmoName}" FontSize="14" TextAlignment="Center"           
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Refresh" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=WebBrowser, Path=ReloadCommand}"/>
</Grid>

<!--<Rectangle Width="1920" Height="1200" IsEnabled="False"/>-->
<wpf:WebView2 Source="{Binding HostName}" Width="320" Height="180" IsEnabled="False" x:Name="WebBrowser"/>
```

Button references to element WebView2 with name called "WebBrowser", but what property for binding have I to use instead of ReloadCommand to invoke  refreshing the page with this Button?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Click event handler that calls [`WebView2.Reload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2.reload?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1210.39#microsoft-web-webview2-wpf-webview2-reload).